# Different SQL behaviour between phpMyAdmin and PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to understand why this SQL statement is not working once I run the script.

If i make the query manually in phpMyadmin, it returns the correct result; but once the script runs with the same query in it, the query is returning nothing.

This is my query:

btw: `$heute` is this:

```
$date_array = getdate();
$heute = $date_array[mday]."/".$date_array[mon]."/".$date_array[year];


$sql = "SELECT email, was, wo, entfernung FROM jobsperemail WHERE haufigkeit='1' AND WHERE bestatigt='ja' AND last_sent!='$heute'";
```

This is my DB schema:

[image: my DB table schema]

And these are the table values:

[image: the table with values]

Can someone please help me?

Comment: You have two `WHERE` keywords in your query.  Remove the second one.

Comment: Don't store dates as `VARCHAR`, store them as `DATE`s. It's far more efficient in just about every possible way. Sorting, field size, readability, portability, the fact that you can use native date functions without im/explicit conversions, etc.

Comment: @MikeChristensen THANKS A LOT. please write your sentence as an answer, i will check as the best. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your SQL query:

```
SELECT email, was, wo, entfernung FROM jobsperemail WHERE haufigkeit='1' AND WHERE bestatigt='ja' AND last_sent!='$heute'
```

You'll need to remove the second `WHERE` keyword, as such:

```
SELECT email, was, wo, entfernung FROM jobsperemail WHERE haufigkeit='1' AND bestatigt='ja' AND last_sent!='$heute'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have the php variable in the query.

Inside script the php variable ($heute) is interpreted but in phpmyadmin it isn't

if I can help you further just let me know

Comment: thanks, but of course i will replace the variable heute in phpadmin. but the problem solved. :D thanks much